# Changing game engine after releasing an ios gaming app

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, gamesalad

I have been developing my gaming app using **game salad** engine, after releasing my app i decided to change to **unity** for several reasons, is it possible to change the game build after releasing with a totally new build using a new engine?
and does this affect **Non-Consumable** in app purchases that people already did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can. just rebuild the game in unity, and I mean create it again.

For non-consumables iaps, you will have to make a **Restore Purchases** button, which is easy in Unity.

[This](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/ads-analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game) is a tutorial for IAPs on Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really helped

Comment: just did, sorry 1st time for me here :)